# Radius of influence?

Tags: modeling

I'm on blender Currently in edit mode and am trying to create low poly maps. I did all the steps but I can't create a radius of influence3 that circle around your cursor which allows your chunks or fragments of my plane to grow together does somebody know how to create one?

Answer (score 1):

To activate/deactivate [proportional edit](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html#proportional-edit) in edit mode, use <kbd>O</kbd>.

Alternatively, use this toggle in the top bar of the 3D viewport

[image]

Comment: thank you, this helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

To make the circle around your cursor bigger or smaller you use the mouse scroll wheel. Scroll up to make the circle smaller, and down to make it bigger. If for some reason the circle was much larger than the area in the viewport, or so small it isn't visible, you may not have realized it was there. It is possible to need to scroll for a while to make the circle come in range, if previously it had been used on a large area and now you want to use it on a small one.

Comment: thank you, this helped me out.